# Redirect the customer to Previous Page after registration in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, forms, registration, customer-registration

I want to create one functionality for the customer registration process.

- if registration is initiated from a particular page, then it should redirect to the same page after registration completion and show a success message on the page.
- If the email is already registered, it should redirect to customer/account/login, by showing an error.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done like this,

here is di.xml from the path app/code/Vendor/Module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Override\Account\CreatePost"/>
</config>
```

here is CreatePost.php from the path app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Override/Account

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Override\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface as CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Helper\Address;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class CreatePost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $accountManagement;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Helper\Address
     */
    protected $addressHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
     */
    protected $formFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory
     */
    protected $subscriberFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $regionDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $addressDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Registration
     */
    protected $registration;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $customerDataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
     */
    protected $customerUrl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    protected $escaper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor
     */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
     */
    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var AccountRedirect
     */
    private $accountRedirect;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private $cookieMetadataManager;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    private $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepository
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Session $customerSession,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
    Address $addressHelper,
    UrlFactory $urlFactory,
    FormFactory $formFactory,
    SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
    RegionInterfaceFactory $regionDataFactory,
    AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
    CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerDataFactory,
    CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
    Registration $registration,
    Escaper $escaper,
    CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    AccountRedirect $accountRedirect,
    CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
    Validator $formKeyValidator = null
) {
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    $this->addressHelper = $addressHelper;
    $this->urlModel = $urlFactory->create();
    $this->customerUrl = $customerUrl;
    $this->registration = $registration;
    $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
    $this->accountRedirect = $accountRedirect;
    $this->formKeyValidator = $formKeyValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Validator::class);
    parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $customerSession,
            $scopeConfig,
            $storeManager,
            $accountManagement,
            $addressHelper,
            $urlFactory,
            $formFactory,
            $subscriberFactory,
            $regionDataFactory,
            $addressDataFactory,
            $customerDataFactory,
            $customerUrl,
            $registration,
            $escaper,
            $customerExtractor,
            $dataObjectHelper,
            $accountRedirect,
            $customerRepository
        );
    }
    /**
     * Create customer account action.
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @throws InputException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->registration->isAllowed()) {
            $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()
            || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())
        ) {
            $url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/login', ['_secure' => true]);
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()
                ->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($url));
        }
        $this->session->regenerateId();
        try {
            $address = $this->extractAddress();
            $addresses = $address === null ? [] : [$address];
            $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
            $customer->setAddresses($addresses);
            $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');
            $confirmation = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation');
            $redirectUrl = $this->session->getBeforeAuthUrl();
            $this->checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation);

            $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionAttributes->setIsSubscribed($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false));
            $customer->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

            $customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'customer_register_success',
                ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
            );
            $confirmationStatus = $this->accountManagement->getConfirmationStatus($customer->getId());
            if ($confirmationStatus === AccountManagementInterface::ACCOUNT_CONFIRMATION_REQUIRED) {
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__(
                    'Registration completed. Please verify your account by clicking on the link sent on your registered email id.'
                ));
                //$url = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/index', ['_secure' => true]);
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            } else {
                $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                $this->messageManager->addMessage($this->getMessageManagerSuccessMessage());
                $requestedRedirect = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
                if (!$this->scopeConfig->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $requestedRedirect) {
                    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->success($requestedRedirect));
                    $this->accountRedirect->clearRedirectCookie();
                    return $resultRedirect;
                }
                $resultRedirect = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirect();
            }
            if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
                $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
                $metadata->setPath('/');
                $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
            }

            return $resultRedirect;
        } catch (StateException $e) {
            /*$this->messageManager->addComplexErrorMessage(
                'customerAlreadyExistsErrorMessage',
                [
                    'url' => $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword'),
                ]
            );*/
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Email Already Registered. Please login from here.'));
        } catch (InputException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error->getMessage());
            }
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
        }
        $this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        $defaultUrl = $this->urlModel->getUrl('*/*/login', ['_secure' => true]);
        return $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->error($defaultUrl));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve success message
     *
     * @deprecated 102.0.4
     * @see getMessageManagerSuccessMessage()
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getSuccessMessage()
    {
        if ($this->addressHelper->isVatValidationEnabled()) {
            if ($this->addressHelper->getTaxCalculationAddressType() == Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your shipping address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            } else {
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
                $message = __(
                    'If you are a registered VAT customer, please <a href="%1">click here</a> to enter your billing address for proper VAT calculation.',
                    $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit')
                );
                // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
            }
        } else {
            $message = __('Registration completed. Please verify your account by clicking on the link sent on your registered email id.');
        }
        return $message;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie manager
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager
     */
    private function getCookieManager()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataManager) {
            $this->cookieMetadataManager = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataManager;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cookie metadata factory
     *
     * @deprecated 100.1.0
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private function getCookieMetadataFactory()
    {
        if (!$this->cookieMetadataFactory) {
            $this->cookieMetadataFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->cookieMetadataFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve success message manager message
     *
     * @return MessageInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function getMessageManagerSuccessMessage(): MessageInterface
    {
        if ($this->addressHelper->isVatValidationEnabled()) {
            if ($this->addressHelper->getTaxCalculationAddressType() == Address::TYPE_SHIPPING) {
                $identifier = 'customerVatShippingAddressSuccessMessage';
            } else {
                $identifier = 'customerVatBillingAddressSuccessMessage';
            }

            $message = $this->messageManager
                ->createMessage(MessageInterface::TYPE_SUCCESS, $identifier)
                ->setData(
                    [
                        'url' => $this->urlModel->getUrl('customer/address/edit'),
                    ]
                );
        } else {
            $message = $this->messageManager
                ->createMessage(MessageInterface::TYPE_SUCCESS)
                ->setText(
                    __('Registration completed. Please verify your account by clicking on the link sent on your registered email id.')
                );
        }

        return $message;
    }
}
```